# Webpack with Babel compile fine but I get Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not define

Tags: babeljs, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

I am having some trouble implementing webpack with babel in a project I inherited.

I would like to use babel and webpack on an existing project, but i get Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not define.

Here is my webpack config:

```
 const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
 const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
 const webpack = require('webpack');
 const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
 const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: `${__dirname}/src/index.js`,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
 plugins: [
 new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
   template: "./public/index.html",
   filename: "./index.html",
   minify: {
     removeComments: true,
     collapseWhitespace: true,
     removeAttributeQuotes: true
    }
  }),
  new TerserPlugin({
    parallel: true,
    terserOptions: {
      ecma: 6,
    },
    })
   ],
 devServer: {
 inline: true,
 hot: true
 },
 devtool: 'sourcemap',
 module: {
   rules: [
    {
     test: /\.jsx?$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
   {
    test: /locales/,
    loader: '@alienfast/i18next-loader',
   },
   {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
   },
   {
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'html-loader'
   },
   {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
   },
   {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
       },
      ],
    },
   ]
   },
   resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  node: {
   fs: "empty"
  } 
 };
```

here is my babel config file:

```
 {
 "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
 "plugins": [ "transform-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread", 
 "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
 "sourceType": "unambiguous",
 }
```

I trued quite some combination already but I am stuck, any help would be welcome :)